# How do I set Entity constructor parameter from a Form Type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I need to pass a parameter to the constructor of an Entity that is being used in a Form Type.

I'm setting the entity from the Form Type in the setDefaultOptions method:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity'
    ));
}
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity',
        'my_parameter' => 'some value'
    ));
}
```

so that it would be injected through the constructor.

Is this possible? (I'm using Symfony 2.2)

Comment: Why do you need a value? For "fetch" a set (or a single, accurate) entity?

Comment: I just want to pass a parameter to the entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form type never creates any entity object. So it seems it doesn't make any sense to pass arguments for entity constructor.

Setting `data_class` option is not even necessary to couple the form with entity object. In most cases data class is guessed based on an object passed to form builder.

From Symfony docs:

> Every form needs to know the name of the class that holds the
>   underlying data (e.g. Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task). Usually, this is
>   just guessed based off of the object passed to the second argument to
>   createForm (i.e. $task). Later, when you begin embedding forms, this
>   will no longer be sufficient. So, while not always necessary, it's
>   generally a good idea to explicitly specify the data_class option
>   (...)

**edit**:

An example:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function fooAction()
    {
         $entityObject = new MyEntity($someArgument);

         // now we create form:
         $form = $this->createForm(new BarFormType(), $entityObject);

         // then you can bind form:
         $form->bind($this->getRequest());

         // ... and enjoy your data :)
         printf("Hello %s", $entityObject->getValuePassedByUserViaForm());
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in the case of a page that shows the form, how can I pass a parameter to the entity?

Comment: Im not sure if I understood you. Let me try clarify: you connect entity object with the form by passing the entity object as a second argument to createForm method (form factory). That means that you need create an entity object before. Next, when you submit form and bind request - entity object is filled with data passed through the form. I've extended my answer with an example

Comment: Correct. I was looking this from the wrong side at that moment.

Comment: "The form never creates an entity object" - this statement isn't exactly true. If the form has attached subforms that are required, it absolutely will create an instance of the class for that subform, and it will do so passing the constructor zero arguments:  See FormType::configureOptions where it calls new $class().

Thus, the answer below from Maksim is more helpful in some cases

Answer (score 12):

I think you looking for this http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html#option-2-provide-a-closure

Let's say you have data Money object which takes two arguments amount and currency. Here's a form type for such object:

```
<?php
class MoneyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('amount', 'number')
            ->add('currency', 'text')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foo\Model\Money',
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return new Money(
                    $form->getData()['amount'],
                    $form->getData()['currency']
                );
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but if there is not any "setCurrency", an Exception is thrown. Have you solved this case?

Comment: Do you have only one currency? Do not want to show it on form? If so

I believe it is possible to pass Options to empty_data closure as second argument. So you can remove a form field currency and take it from options.

Comment: For me, it was `$form->get('amount')->getData()` etc that worked

Comment: Any ideas how to pass parent form value to the clojure? `$form->getParent()->getData()`; seems not to be set yet on the run time.

Comment: @mmoreram To solve the Exception thrown where there are not setters see the complete answer (and complete example) here https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/#data-mappers